# Difference between .at(index) and .charAt(index)

Tags: javascript, string

What is the difference between the following two functions?

```
let str = 'hello world';
str.at(6) // w
str.charAt(6) // w
```

The only difference that I can find in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) is that `.at()` accepted negative indices, is there another difference?

Comment: `.charAt()` is available in [all kinds of browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_string_charat) (1997, [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt#browser_compatibility)), while `.at()` was [recently added](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_string_at) (2021).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things I can recall:

- obviously browser support, `at()` is newer
- when out of range, `at()` returns `undefined` and `charAt()` returns an empty string
- negative indices (already mentioned by you)

Answer (score 0):

Both methods will return a new string consisting of a single UTF-16 encoded character located at the specified offset o the string.

The difference is that `.at` accepts negative numbers, and it is a much newer feature, so older versions of some engines might not support it.

Another difference is the default value returned if the number provided as a parameter exceeds the length of the string. `.at` will return `undefined` while `.charAt` will return an empty string.

You can find more information here ([.at()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/at)) and here ([.charAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt))